# simple present or present perfect, which one to use and when?

Tags: grammar, verbs, present-perfect, present-tense, past-simple

So, to be more specific, I am confused between when to use the simple past tense and when to use the present perfect(has/have)? Based on the context, can anyone please tell me when to use them and how? Also, which one out of the following is correct:-

1. I don't think I ever mentioned out here.
2. I don't think I have ever mentioned out here

Which one to use? Or is there any better way to say/write?

Comment: First of all, your sentences don't even consist of simple present tense. Secondly, your sentences don't make sense at all. The comma shouldn't be present after "think".

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I'm more focused on clearing my doubts about the simple present and present perfect tenses. So, I would appreciate it if you could tell me the difference between them. If the above sentences look wrong to you, could you please correct them and let me know the correct difference between them?

Comment: I feel this community is created for English language learners to learn, share their knowledge, and FYI Google search also shows the results from this community as their first preference. Once again, please focus on answering the questions instead of providing suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I found the below answer:-

1. Simple Present - It generally is used for the activities that have been performed many times.
2. Present Perfect - Basically, for the activities that were either performed once/or for the first time or never performed earlier.

So considering the above example, the present perfect tense should be appropriate.
i.e.
I don't think, I have ever mentioned out here